# How to know which Exception Came for JSF 2.0 / Debugging JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Environment
RAD 8.5, JSF 2.0, Primfaces 3.5 Websphere

How to know what exception came in JSF 2.0. When I am working with one of the page (construction with JSF2.0 and Primefaces 3.5). When I click button in the page console shows just one line error message as written below

```
[ERROR   ] An exception occurred
```

Could some please tell me how to find what exception came, Adding trace gives detail for back end processing, it doesn't give any additional information about this error.

Comment: Please give us more information about your environment. Which server are you using? Are you using a logging framework?

Comment: I have already written the environment. Server is websphere 8.5. I am not aware of logging. Can you please give me some more info